# How to disable auto thumbnails rotation in Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, windows-explorer, images, thumbnails

Windows 8 has a nice feature that it rotates thumbnails of images if they captured vertically. but sometimes it's pesky.

How can be this feature disabled?

For example (ignore the language):
[image]

Comment: It's reading the metadata on the image(s) to determine orientation.  If they aren't appearing rotated properly, then the image file needs its metadata fixed.

Comment: @techie007, I think this is the question :) how to tell Windows not to read this metadata but display any image as previous Windows versions are displaying.

Comment: Dunno if (and I doubt) there's a way, as they are following the current standard.  You may have to remove the EXIF orientation data from the images to get your desired effect.

Answer (score 2):

At this time no one at Microsoft is willing to tell a way to make explorer ignore the rotation tag on the EXIF data - see [here](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-pictures/how-do-you-turn-off-windows-8-photo-auto-rotation/a46e935b-cc99-473f-8291-78ca8417f517). Seems it's built-in and the only chance is they reconsider the scenario and patch it via Windows Update to make explorer do that depending on a registry setting.

If you want Windows to stop rotating the thumbnail of a specific image you can use a poor workaround: open the image in the photo viewer, rotate it and then undo the job. This will clear the EXIF tag.

If you want to get rid of this annoyance, you can try alternative thumbnail generation software which doesn't do that. You can try the powerful thumbnail generator [Sagethumbs](https://code.google.com/p/sagethumbs/) or some photo viewer software which integrates its own thumbnail generation function.

Comment: Thanks. in fact, this workaround doesn't help cause I need the EXIF data and I'm using it all time.
Actually, if there is an edit in the registry or any conf-file that can fix it, it would be great. indeed, I'm using FastStone Image Viewer for that, I just prefer to have this without 3rd party SW.

Comment: So, the answer is no, the setting doesn't exist yet.